# Executing python script built under different virtual environment/venv?

Tags: python, virtualenv, invoke, virtualenvwrapper

I apologize if what I'm trying to achieve is not Pythonic - I recently moved to the language.

I have a project directory structured like so:

```
root
--proj1
----venv
----main.py
--proj2
----venv
----main.py
```

Both proj1 and proj2 run under their own virtual environments. I am trying to call proj2/main.py from proj1/main.py, whilst executing proj2/main.py under its own venv. I have tried:

```
import subprocess

s2_out = subprocess.check_output([sys.executable, r"..\proj2\__main__.py", "arg"])
```

This invokes successfully, but I am getting all manner of not found exceptions, etc. I am guessing this is the reason why.

Please let me know if there is a better approach!

Comment: Do you use `pyenv` by any chance? I know how to do this if you use `pyenv`.

Comment: @PeacefulJames Nope - but please elaborate I'm open to adopting it if it will help :)

Comment: Is there an overriding reason you need to have 2 venvs?  You’re going to have fairly unreliable behavior unless you set things up correctly.  i.e. if you activate venv1 you should be able to import proj2.main because things were configured  correctly. Anything else is building on sand. Yet doing that is non trivial as well which is why I hesitate to think your config as is is a good path to start on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```py
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["python_interpreter location (python.exe)", "python file"])
```

So you could do:

```py
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["../proj2/bin/python.exe", "proj2/main.py"])
```

For Mac OS and Linux, the `python` interpreter path for a venv would be `folder/bin/python.exe`, or in your case `../proj2/bin/python.exe`.

For Windows, the `python` interpreter path for a venv would be `folder/scripts/python.exe`.

You may need to include the full paths.

Another way to do this could be using [`subprocess.call`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor), if you need the output:

```py
import subprocess

output = subprocess.call("%s %s" %("../proj2/bin/python.exe", "proj2/main.py"))
print(output)
```

Both ways will work just fine :)

Comment: Tell me if you need me to elaborate.

Comment: For a venv, python.exe should be in scripts.

Comment: I think it would be `path/to/venv/bin/python` under Linux/Mac and `path/to/venv/Scripts/python.exe` under Windows (if I remember correctly). But essentially this is the answer I would suggest as well.

Comment: Worked well, I didn't realize I could specify the interpreter. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Hey this is not a complete answer but is how I would approach it.
If you use `pyenv` then this would be the approach:

1. Make a separate virtualenv for each project. `pyenv virtualenv 3.8 proj1` and `pyenv virtualenv 3.7 proj1` or whatever the python versions are.
2. use `pyenv local` in each directory to link the dirs to the venvs
3. `cd` to each directory and in each one the python env should activate. Use `pip install` to install the libs to each venv.
4. Now you should have access to different python executables that use separate libs, e.g. `~/.pyenv/versions/proj1/bin/python`
5. So from proj1 code you should theoretically be able to do:

```
import os;
os.system("~/.pyenv/versions/proj2/bin/python ../proj2/main.py")
```

or something like that.
I have not actually tried this but I am fairly certain it would work for using separate libs.

Here is pyenv: https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv

I will try it myself tomorrow when I am not sleepy.

Comment: Thanks man, I was setting up pyenv but went with the simple solution :)